# Trying to make smart combobox item interaction

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am here to find out is it possible to complete my idea to save me time writing long code.

I have 1 main combobox with various items and some other comboboxed. Each combobox of them is called "Combo" + the item from the main combobox.
and I wonder can I, when I click on an item to hide the last used combobox and to show the combobox linked to this item?
1. hide last used combobox
2. show the combobox responding to the selected item from the main combox

```
Public Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

Dim SelectedAction As String = "Combo" + ComboBox2.Text
lastcombobox.visible = false
' now to assign to the new combobox
lastcombobox = (SelectedAction as name of combobox) combobox
Lastcombobox.visible = true
End Sub
```

Comment: The items collection can hold `Objects` not just strings.  Aim your Google at *DataBinding* and read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are not controls. Strings are the data type of Control.Name; that is the Name property of the control object. You cannot cast a string to a control but all is not lost. Create your other Combo Boxes at design time and stack them on top of each other. Notice the Static keyword before lastComboBox. This persists the value between calls to the method. You could accomplish the same thing by making this variable a class level variable. The first time the method is called their will be nothing in lastComboBox therefore the check for IsNothhing. Control.Find returns an array so we must refer to ctl(0) - the first element of the array, since we know it will return only one.

```
Private Sub Combo2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combo2.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim SelectedAction As String = "Combo" & Combo2.Text
        Static lastComboBox As ComboBox
        If Not IsNothing(lastComboBox) Then
            lastComboBox.Visible = False
        End If
        Dim ctl() As Control = Controls.Find(SelectedAction, True)
        lastComboBox = CType(ctl(0), ComboBox)
        lastComboBox.BringToFront()
        lastComboBox.Visible = True
End Sub
```